# How to run Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am very new to this and seem to always have issues with python and running things from the the command line. I have been following these instructions:

https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running.html#starting-the-notebook-server

When I get to the step where I am to type "jupyter notebook" in the command line nothing happens.

Comment: Did you install it with pip?

Comment: Do you have a default Web browser configured on your system? Or perhaps the browser isn't coming to the front because it's already open? What OS are you using anyway?

Comment: @kindall he can go to this address from his browser right? `localhost:8888/tree`

Comment: Yeah, if it doesn't launch your browser automatically you can just go to `http://localhost:8888`. But it should launch your browser automatically.

Comment: Yes, typo, sorry.

Comment: so by typing in the command is that permanently flicking the on switch to jupyter notebook?

Comment: @AlexUngar when you run `jupyter notebook` you are starting the notebook server on port 8888. By typing that address in your browser you are just connecting to the server which is already running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check `localhost:8888` in your browser? 
If that does not work, then in your anaconda command prompt, try `conda install jupyter notebook` to make sure that it is installed correctly

Comment: you can install without conda also using `sudo pip install jupyter`

Comment: @Mohammad Yusuf Ghazi  Thanks, forgot to mention pip as well. If you are not using linux-based environment(for example windows), `pip install jupyter` will suffice.

Comment: I now am having issues installing the Anaconda package. I had uninstalled it and am now attempting to re-install but getting "Failed to create Anaconda menus"

Comment: I honestly have no idea where to go from here. I have deleted every trace I can find of python and Anaconda and keep trying to install it but same issue. I have tried following msarahans advice but I don't really understand what he is saying. I am running windows 10. I dont understand what happened.

I installed it once wihtout problem. I typed "jupyter notebook" into the command line and nothing happened. I assumed something was wrong with the install or something so I uninstalled it. Now I am where I am.